# React native run-ios ignoring simulator option

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

using the following commands my last used simulator iPhone 8 Plus (iOS 13.2) is used. Any thoughts on how to work out why the specified simulator is not launching?

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator "iPad"
```

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad"
```

These commands without npx also do not launch an iPad simulator but the iPhone 8 Plus.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do just open the workspace from the ios folder of your app and try to run the application from there as there you have lots of options available to run it. Moreover you have clear understanding of bugs from there.

I hope this helps...Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks this worked! Hm now my question is what is the difference between running it out of xcode via this method and react-native-cli that is causing the simulator option to be ignored. Do you think looking into the react-native-cli source is a good idea?

Comment: better to run through the workspace area when you are using ios, this is because you will get better clarity of the bugs as xcode will takes care of it. Through the cli it is difficult to run as its not states clearly what is happening in the project...I hope this helps...Thanks :)
If it helps, you can upvote and accept the answer as well thanks :)